# Check wether all checked checkboxes have value=right and all unchecked checkboxes have value=wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ive been at this for days now, have asked numerous sources, but still can't find how to do this.
I have seen bits of code here and there, but am yet to see an implementation that works.

```
<fieldset id="question">
  <legend>Which are fruit?</legend>
     <label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="q1" VALUE="wrong">tomatoes<BR></label>
     <label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="q2" VALUE="wrong">cucumber<BR></label>
     <label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="q3" VALUE="right">apples<BR></label>
     <label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="q4" VALUE="wrong">onion<BR></label>
     <label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="q5" VALUE="right">bananas<BR></label>
  </fieldset>
<input type="button" id="answer">
```

I think I might have structured my question poorly previously and will try again, I'm really quite desperate.

On submit, if all checkboxes with value 'right' are checked, and all checkboxes with value 'wrong' are unchecked, I want to display a 'well done' alert message.

Could someone please help out with the javascript for this.

I am thinking that it should be something like:

```
If (all checkboxes with value 'right' = checked) and (all checkboxes with value 'wrong' are unchecked) {
do something}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
if($('[value=right]:checked').length==3 && $('[value=wrong]:not(:checked)').length==2)
   //show message well done.....
```

if you do not have the count for checkboxes with value:

```
 if($('[value=right]:checked').length==$('[value=right]').length && $('[value=wrong]:not(:checked)').length==$('[value=wrong]').length)
   //show message well done.....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can tell if any checked checkboxes have the value "wrong" like this:

```
var wrongChecked = $("input:checkbox:checked[value='wrong']").length != 0;
```

Similarly, you can check the unchecked checkboxes:

```
var rightUnchecked = $("input:checkbox[value='right']").not(":checked").length != 0;
```

If either of those two variables ends up `true`, then the state of the checkboxes is wrong. If they're both `false`, it's correct:

```
if (!wrongChecked && !rightUnchecked) {
  // yaay! correct answer!
}
```